# Shifting (sub)figure caption in case of merged figures

Tags: spacing, graphics, floats

I have a small piece of code that merges two figures:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.5\textwidth}
  \hspace*{-1.5cm}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{images/Figure1.pdf}
  \captionof{figure}{My Figure1 Caption}
  \label{Figure1}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
  \hspace*{2cm}{
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{images/Figure2.pdf}
  \captionof{figure}{My Figure2 Caption}}
  \label{Figure2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

**Question**: Any idea how to shift the caption of the second figure (i.e. the text "Figure2: My Figure2 Caption") to the right, so that it aligns with the second figure which has been shifted?

Comment: Why do you shift your figures with those `\hspace` commands inside the `minipage`s? Can't you just shift the whole `minipage`?

Comment: Along the lines of what Gonzalo suggests, and without knowing the size of your images, does this work: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{images/Figure1.pdf}
  \captionof{figure}{My Figure1 Caption}
  \label{Figure1}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace*{.2\textwidth}%
\begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[scale=0.4]{images/Figure2.pdf}
  \captionof{figure}{My Figure2 Caption}
  \label{Figure2}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
\end{document}`

Comment: Correct Steven, see my answer below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a way by adjusting the minpage's width:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{minipage}[t]{.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=FIGURE1_SCALE]{images/Figure1.pdf}
\caption{My Figure1 Caption}
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.3\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[scale=FIGURE2_SCALE]{images/Figure2.pdf}
\caption{My Figure2 Caption}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Still interested if there is a way to separately shift the figure caption.

Comment: You forgot  something in your code. `\begin{figure}...\end{document}`!!